# Replace \n by \\n

Tags: c#

I have a xml string shown below:

```
String xml = @"<axislable='ihgyh\nuijh\nkjjfgj'>";
```

Now when I try to output the xml it shows  `<axislable='ihgyh\nuijh\nkjjfgj'>`

But my requirement is to break the line like below

```
<axislable='ihgyh
uijh
kjjfgj'>
```

I have tried replacing the xml using  `xml = xml.Replace("\n", "\\n");`   But it doesnt seems to work.Any ideas how to break the line?

Regards,
Sharmila

Comment: Just don't use verbatim string literal, backslashes in it don't escape anything. Remove @.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the `@` prefix:

```
var xml = "<axislable='ihgyh\nuijh\nkjjfgj'>";
```

Also you may need `"\r\n"` instead:

```
var xml = "<axislable='ihgyh\r\nuijh\r\nkjjfgj'>";
```

Comment: This is really the best answer here, just don't use the @ for verbatim strings.

Answer (score 3):

It's not working since you have no line breaks in your string. Your string contains the substring "\n".

Notice you use the `@` operator.

Try the following:

```
xml = xml.Replace("\\n", "\n");
```

Comment: @ isn't an operator - it's just part of the syntax for a verbatim string literal.

Comment: Thank you :) but i need the character \n to be replace by \\n like <axislable='ihgyh\\nuijh\\nkjjfgj'>

Comment: @JonSkeet pardon me for my English as it's not my native language (nor I knew what's the correct English definition for the verbatim symbol), thanks for the correction though

Answer (score 1):

Try

`xml.Replace(@"\n", Envioroment.NewLine);`

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Leo's answer (sorry don't know how to comment on your answer)

```
String xml = String.Format("<axislable='ihgyh{0}uijh{0}kjjfgj'>", Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Check _Add comment_ button in the bottom of any answer ;)

Comment: I don't see the Add comment button on other people's answers, only mine :(

Answer (score 1):

The @ character means that the string is a *verbatim* string, meaning that escape characters like \n in the string are not processed and treated as text.

The following string is a regular string:

```
string xml="<axislable='ihgyh\nuijh\nkjjfgj'>";
```

and translates the \n escape sequence to a newline as you would expect.

You should check the [documentation on string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) for the difference between the two forms.

Comment: Thank you all :) I got it to work by using xml.Replace(@"\n", @"\\n");